# What is appium, selendroid and selenium and how they are working?

Tags: selenium, appium, selendroid

I am confused in between above appium,selendroid and selenium and how it is interacting with each other ?

Can anybody help me to sort my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Appium :** Appium is open source automation tool which used to automate native, mobile web and hybrid application. 
Following are the things which come with appium

1. Appium is open source  automation tool.
2. Cross platform test automation tool for mobile applications.
3. Support native, mobile web application and hybrid application.
4. Appium is based on client-server architecture.
5. Appium server written in Node.js.
6. Appium dose not bound you in any specific language or framework to write or run your test.
7. Recompile of application not necessary while running script.
8. Inherits selenium features hence easy for selenium users.

**Selenium :** it is used for web application automation framework.

**Selendroid :**  It is the framework which used in performing mobile automation.

For mobile automation selendroid and appium used

if your android api > 17 then appium works but if your android api <= 17 you shuld use selendroid.